# Python - Add hook/callback for when cursor moves when entering raw_input?

Tags: python, terminal, syntax-highlighting, readline, raw-input

I am trying to write a version of the interactive interpreter which has syntax highlighting.

Here's what I have so far which works reasonably well (uses **blessings** and **pygments** modules)...

```
import code
import readline
import threading
import blessings
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import TerminalFormatter
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer

def check_line():
    global current_line
    try:
        while True:
            line = readline.get_line_buffer()
            if line != current_line:
                current_line = line
                do_colour()
    except:
        pass

def do_colour():
    global terminal

    raw_line = readline.get_line_buffer()
    line = highlight(raw_line, lexer, formatter)[:-1]

    with terminal.location(x = 4):
        print line,

    readline.redisplay()

current_line = ''
terminal = blessings.Terminal()
lexer = PythonLexer()
formatter = TerminalFormatter()
console = code.InteractiveConsole()

colour_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_line)
colour_thread.setDaemon(True)
colour_thread.start()

console.interact('')
```

It does colour the lines as you type them...

[image: Syntax highlighting in interactive prompt]

The problems are;

1. This uses a separate thread to busy-check for changes in the line (think this might be using a whole core)
2. If you move cursor back through a line, then move it back to the right, the terminal redraws the character that was just unselected, and it does it in white

What I really want is a callback/hook for when the cursor moves or the line buffer changes - are either of these things possible? Can I put stdin into byte-by-byte mode, then somehow pass the bytes to an internal buffered version of raw_input, and also fire the callback?

P.S it also doesn't deal with multi-line strings (`"""like this"""`) at the moment, but this isn't a very difficult fix.

---

**Edit:**

Ok, I have kind of got there, here's the latest code...

```
import code, ctypes, readline, blessings, signal, threading
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import TerminalFormatter
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer

def slight_delay():
    threading.Timer(0.001, draw).start()
    return 0

def draw():  
    raw_line = readline.get_line_buffer()
    line = highlight(raw_line, lexer, formatter)[:-1]

    with lock:
        with terminal.location(x = 4):
            print line,
        readline.redisplay()

def keyboard_interrupt(c, frame):   # Ctrl-C throws in C code otherwise
    pass

callback = ctypes.PYFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int)(slight_delay)
hook_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(ctypes.pythonapi,"PyOS_InputHook")
hook_ptr.value = ctypes.cast(callback, ctypes.c_void_p).value
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, keyboard_interrupt)

terminal = blessings.Terminal()
lexer = PythonLexer()
formatter = TerminalFormatter()
console = code.InteractiveConsole()
lock = threading.Lock()

console.interact('')
```

The thing I was looking for was [PyOS_InputHook](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/045e7a587f3c/Modules/readline.c#l1015) which is called

1. On every key press
2. Every 0.1 seconds

So this means I could ditch the busy watch thread and means I don't use (almost) any CPU.

The final problem was that the input hook is called **immediately** on key press; before the input has been read from stdin and (for printable chars) attached to the line buffer. The result was that there was a 0.1 second delay to colouring the most recent character.

I solved this in a bit a of a hacky way by doing the drawing in a thread on a 0.001 second delay.

Comment: nice, if you estimate the readline delay is too long or should be user defined : feel free to drop a line there https://bugs.python.org/issue35243